# Is it true that $X\simeq X'$, $Y\simeq Y'$ implies $Y/f(X)\simeq Y'/f'(X')$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

Let $X,X',Y,Y'$ be topological spaces (for the sake of readability I do not write the topologies) and suppose we are given
$$
f: X\to Y\qquad\text{continuous},\\
f': X'\to Y'\qquad\text{continuous},\\
g:X\to X'\qquad\text{homotopy equivalence},\\
g':X'\to X\qquad\text{homotopy inverse of } g,\\
h:Y\to Y'\qquad\text{homotopy equivalence},\\
h':Y'\to Y\qquad\text{homotopy inverse of } h,\\
f'\circ g=h\circ f.
$$
Is it true that $Y/f(X)\simeq Y'/f'(X')$?

Here is what I have done:

Let $\pi:Y\to Y/f(X)$ and $\pi':Y'\to Y'/f'(X')$ be the canonical (continuous) surjections. Using
$$
Y\overset{h}{\longrightarrow}Y'\overset{\pi'}{\longrightarrow}Y'/f'(X'),\\
Y'\overset{h'}{\longrightarrow}Y\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow}Y/f(X)
$$
I have constructed, using also the extra condition $f'\circ g=h\circ f$, continuous maps $\varphi:Y/f(X)\to Y'/f'(X')$ and $\varphi':Y'/f'(X')\to Y/f(X)$ such that
$$
\varphi\circ\pi=\pi'\circ h,\\
\varphi'\circ\pi'=\pi\circ h'
$$
which then yields
$$
\varphi'\circ\varphi\circ\pi=\pi\circ h'\circ h,\\
\varphi\circ\varphi'\circ\pi'=\pi'\circ h\circ h'.
$$
But know I'm having trouble defining a homotopy for $\varphi'\circ\varphi$ resp. $\varphi\circ\varphi'$. Because if say $H:Y\times[0,1]\to Y$ is such that $H(y,0)=y, H(y,1)=h'(h(y))$ for all $y\in Y$, then it is very tempting to define
$$
A:Y/f(X)\times[0,1]\to Y/f(X)\\
\pi(y)\mapsto \pi(H(y,t)),
$$
but this might be ill defined because there is no way to assure that this doesn't depend on the representative of the class chosen. Can we surpass that problem? Also, I haven't used yet that $g$ is a homotopy equivalence which is kind of suspicious, but I don't see how to use it.

**And last but not least**, is it even true that $Y/f(X)\simeq Y'/f'(X')$? I naively assume it is, because I cannot think of a straightforward way to construct a counterexample.

Comment: What about $X=\{0;1\}$, $Y=[0,1]$ and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ the inclusion. $X'=X$, $Y'=pt$ and $f':X'\rightarrow Y'$ the projection. Let $g:X\rightarrow X'$ be the equality and $h:Y\rightarrow Y'$ the projection. We trivially have $f'g=hf$. But then $Y/X\simeq S^1$ whereas $Y'/f'(X')$ is a point. You should look at homotopy colimits, they have a better behaviour with respect to homotopy.